# Proving Tangent line perpendicular to the radius using Contradiction

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, circles, tangent-line

Here is the proof by contradiction to prove tangent to the circle and radius are Perpendicular at the point of Contact. Let me know whether the proof is Complete.
Consider the circle with center $O$ and tangent drawn to it at the point $H$. By the definition of a tangent, if we join the center $O$ and any other point apart from $H$ on the tangent line say $T$, then it is evident that $$OT>OH=R---(1)$$.

No let us assume that $OH$ is not perpendicular to the tangent. So $\exists$ $OT$ $\perp$ to tangent with $T$ on the tangent line. Now $\Delta OHT$ is a Right angled triangle with the hypotenuse $OH$, so $OH>OT$ contradicting $(1)$. Hence $OH \perp$ to the tangent.

Comment: It is a little bit too much formal, but you could say:
The point $H$ lies on the circle $\gamma$ with radius $R$ and center $O$. Therefore $OH=R$.
Now we want to prove $OH\perp T$, where $T$ is the tangent line to the circle at $H$.
Assume $OH\not\perp T$. Then $\exists$ $OT$ $\perp$ to tangent with $T$ on the tangent line. But then $OT$ is the hypotenuse of $\Delta OHT$, which is a right angled triangle, so $OH>OT$ contradiction.

Comment: We may also prove it this way: Let $O$ be the center. Assume that $OH$ is not perpendicular to the tangent, then $OH$ will make an acute angle with the tangent line. We can then easily find (construct) another point $H'$ on the tangent line so that $OH'=OH=R$. But then the tangent line will cut the circle at two distinct points. This is a contradiction.